# Which geographic coordinate system should I use to work in meters in Angola?

Tags: qgis-plugins, profile, hec-ras

I am using WGS84 in Qgis 2.18, but when I try to use some Qgis Plugins (like Profile Tool and Q-Ras) they don´t work. Is it a coordinate problem? Or something else?

**Profile Tool:**

It makes the profile but the horizontal scale instead of being in meters is something strange (0,002...0,004...etc). The vertical scale is ok.

**Q-Raz:**

Error message states:

> 2018-01-08T18:04:25   1   Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/Users/Jorge Matos/.qgis2/python/plugins\Qgis2Ras\qras_dialog.py",
>   line 113, in runProfile
>   main(self.river,self.XSection,self.textfile,self.dem,resolut‌​ion)
>   File "C:/Users/Jorge Matos/.qgis2/python/plugins\Qgis2Ras\RASout.py",
>   line 284, in main outfile = open(file_strin_path, 'w') IOError: [Errno
>   22] invalid mode ('w') or filename:

Comment: Are you receiving any error messages or warnings using the tools?  The tools may require the data to be in a projected crs and not a geographic crs.

Comment: no geographic coordinate system is going to be in meters. A good projected coordinate system to try would be WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_33S or 34S

Comment: Just to add a little flesh to this, WGS84 is a geographic projection which units are in degrees. To get your measurements in meters, you will need to reproject your data to a projected coordinate system. UTM is a global projection that divides the Earth's surface into zones. Angola falls within Zone 33S and Zone 34S so you should use one of these

Comment: Thanks artwork21, Dylan and Nathan for your tips. All the best.